# Issue with python inserting record containing datetime object into mysql db

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having issues inserting datetime object into mysql. No error message but I do not see the inserted record. I printed the output of the insert, it returned `1`

```
now = datetime(2018, 8, 20, 11, 5, 3)
print now

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=hostname, user=username, passwd=password, db=database)
cur = conn.cursor()
d = cur.execute('INSERT INTO mytable(begin_date, end_date, status) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)',(now,now,"success"))
print d
>>
2018-08-20 11:05:03
1


mysql> describe mytable;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| begin_date | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_date   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status     | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Did you `conn.commit()`?

Comment: you are right, I didnt commit. Thats why. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to commit after execute

```
# Make sure data is committed to the database
 conn.commit()

 cur.close()
 conn.close()
```